# Giving error at - setContentView(R.layout.splash);

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

my splash.java code is:

```
package com.example.copyandroid1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends  Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout);

    }


}
```

Comment: Please add the proper code.

Comment: From the code you have provided, you didn't specify the layout file name, R.layout.YOUR_NAME And you should provide the error stacktrace.

Comment: that's because you should never ever use a splash screen in Android. It's just wrong.

Comment: the code is: setContentView(R.layout.splash);

Comment: Please post your error.

Comment: error: "splash cannot be resolved or is 
  not a field"

Comment: do you create splash.xml inside res/layout ?

Answer (score 0):

`R.layout` is a class while `setContentView()` excepts an `int` (or a `View` if you use the other overload).

Change to

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

where `splash` refers to `res/layout/splash.xml`.

---

> error shown is: "splash cannot be resolved or is not a field."

Then you don't have `splash.xml` in your layout resources folder, or there was some problem building resources and `R.java` was not updated.

Comment: actually the code is: setContentView(R.layout.splash);

Comment: Please edit your question to specify what your problem is, specifically.

Comment: error shown is: "splash cannot be resolved or is not a field."